# Django - How to restrict user for minimum word count in RichTextField - CKEditor?

Tags: python, django, django-models, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm using Django-ckeditor for content section of my page. I want to restrict the users to write at least 100 letters. I tried with `MinLengthValidator`, it does restricts but it is not showing any alert. How do I set up this?

models.py:

```
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = RichTextField(blank=False, null=True, validators=[MinLengthValidator(100)])
```

Is there any built-in feature available in django-ckeditor for this? or any better option available?

Comment: You should do the validation in form level.

Comment: @Gokul nath it is better to do it with ```javascript``` , find ```id``` for that ```<textarea>``` then use this https://sacha.me/Countable/ to count. After that raise a warning or disable button for submit.